Generate list of list round-robin without repetition of items with itertools
If the goal is to achieve f"{x1}-{x2}" pairs where x1 != x2 from a combination, I can do:
import itertools

>>> X = ['1','2','3','4']
>>> [f"-".join(xx) for xx in itertools.combinations(X, 2)]
['1-2', '1-3', '1-4', '2-3', '2-4', '3-4']

But if I want to achieve the desired output some sort of round-robin:
[['2-1', '3-1', '4-1'], ['1-2', '3-2', '4-2'], ['1-3', '2-3', '4-3'], ['1-4', '2-4', '3-4']]

I could have done:
[[f"{x1}-{x2}" for x1 in X if x1 != x2] for x2 in X]

But is there some of round-robin of combinations function in itertools that returns that 2-D lists as shown in the desired output output?
There is a pointer to roundrobin from https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "Visit input iterables in a cycle until each is exhausted."
    # roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') → A D E B F C
    # Algorithm credited to George Sakkis
    iterators = map(iter, iterables)
    for num_active in range(len(iterables), 0, -1):
        iterators = cycle(islice(iterators, num_active))
        yield from map(next, iterators)

But is there a better way to achieve the desired output? Or is the nested loop the most readable and optimal solution to avoid the diagonal?

You could use for x1, x2 in itertools.product(X, 2) instead of the nested loop but I don't think that this would be much better.

What does your "round-robin" have to do with the itertools recipe other than that you named yours that?

Looking carefully at the desired output, it's essentially the lower / upper triangle of a NxN matrix, thus robin-round like, just communicative pairs e.g. 1-3 and 3-1 are considered the same.

Hmm, ok, but the recipe takes something 2D and makes it 1D, rather the opposite of what you want.

Not good, but using itertools:
from itertools import *

X = ['1','2','3','4']
expect = [[f"{x1}-{x2}" for x1 in X if x1 != x2] for x2 in X]

result = [*map(list, batched(starmap('{1}-{0}'.format, permutations(X, 2)), len(X)-1))]

print(result == expect)

First, permutations builds the pairs. Then we flip and format them. Then batched makes it 2D.
Attempt This Online!
